# Different number of rows in extract and live connection of Tableau

Tags: jdbc, tableau-api

In tableau server and desktop (which are installed side by side on a server) with JDBC connection, I got different number of rows for a specific period of time with live connection in comparison with extract mode. The number of rows in the extract mode is less and therefore there is no data for some dates and times. Because of some technical issue, I should use full extract/refresh every day and after a certain day, this problem occurred. Data source and all filters are the same in two modes. Is there any limitation in tableau extract for number of rows or tuple (rows * dimensions)? Is there any limitation about hyper file (extract output) ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare the logs for the Extract vs the Live connection.

For the live connection, check the log.txt file and tabprotosrv.txt files.

For the extract, check the tdeserver.txt file.

[Viewing Underlying SQL Queries](https://community.tableau.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkb.tableau.com%2Farticles%2Fhowto%2Fviewing-underlying-sql-queries-desktop)